# How to access the SharePoint online list anonymously?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I want to give a SharePoint list for anonymous user read access. Here is the list link:

[https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/testlist/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ActionSheet')/items?$select=Title,Id,DateOfLetter,Status/Title,AssignedTo/Title&$expand=Status,AssignedTo](https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/testlist/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(%27ActionSheet%27)/items?$select=Title,Id,DateOfLetter,Status/Title,AssignedTo/Title&$expand=Status,AssignedTo)

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can grant anonymous access to anyone with a guest link for a specific item.

Reference:

[Share SharePoint files or folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-sharepoint-files-or-folders-1fe37332-0f9a-4719-970e-d2578da4941c?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fShare-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US)

For entire list, it is not possible in the SharePoint Online.